# How to display the time in live chat application using SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, chat, signalr

I am currently implementing the chat application. I am using `SignalR` technology for this. In that I would like to add time while the user sharing their information. Help me to update time for user's compact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is best if you show some of your code/effort so would be easy for us to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this tutorials that might help you in your solution

- [Working examples using signalr and asp.net mvc](http://techblog.treenodes.com/index.php/2012/11/25/working-examples-using-signalr-and-asp-net-mvc3/)
- [Using signalr with asp.net mvc to create simple chat application](http://techblog.treenodes.com/index.php/2012/07/17/using-signalr-with-asp-net-mvc-to-create-simple-chat-application/)
- [using signalr with asp.net mvc to create simple chat application part II](http://techblog.treenodes.com/index.php/2012/07/19/using-signalr-with-asp-net-mvc-to-create-simple-chat-application-part-ii/)